# Create image style options, when user is uploading an image

Tags: media

Is there any way to provide image style options, when user is uploading any image and can select any style from the drop down?

Answer (score 1):

[Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert)

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.

more details [Upload images style](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/drupal-howto-get-inline-images-on-your-drupal-site-/14/03/2016/9861)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an image style (say "A") via admin/config/media/image-styles first, when the new image style already created, you can of course choose it (A) from the drop down.